# c# Datalist delete specific row.

Tags: c#

I'm currently developing a guestbook system, and I need admins to remove specific logs. The problem is I'm getting an error when trying to delete it.

The error is: `Index was outside the range. It may not be negative and must be less than the crowd size.
Parameter name: index`

My code: asp.net

```
 <asp:DataList ID="guestBookDataList" runat="server" ondeletecommand="guestBookDataList_DeleteCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="guest-books">
            <span class="guestBook-Id"> # <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %></span><span class="guestBook-Name">Name: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %> </span>
            <span class="guestBook-Date"> Date: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date") %> </span> <br />
            <span class="guestBook-Text"> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "text") %> </span>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonDelete" CssClass="gastbok-remove" runat="server" CommandName="Delete">Delete<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>                
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

My linkbutton is the delete button for each item in the datalist.

And my C# code that's giving me the error:

```
protected void guestBookDataList_DeleteCommand(
    object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(guestBookDataList.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]);
    db.deleteGeustBookLog(id); //calls the sql command
    bindList();
}
```

Basiclly I just need to retrive the guestbooklogs ID from the databse so I can delete it.

Been trying a lot of different methods and googling about this but I can't get it to work. So now I'm asking you. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Add a CommandArgument to the LinkButton with the ID of it. Then in the delete code, look for e.CommandArgument, and pass that value instead.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton2" 
       Text="Delete"
       CommandName="Delete" 
       CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>' 
       OnCommand="DeleteGuestBookEntry" 
       Runat="server"/>
```

You could also give it a commandName like "DeleteGuestBookEntry" or something.

```
  void DeleteGuestBookEntry(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
  {
     int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
     db.deleteGeustBookLog(id); //calls the sql command
     bindList();
  }
```

I'd always check to make sure that your ID is not null, and is numeric, etc, and add some error handling, but that's the down and dirty way to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set "datakeynames" property

```
 <asp:DataList ID="guestBookDataList" runat="server" ondeletecommand="guestBookDataList_DeleteCommand" datakeynames="id">
```