# GUID datatype use in datalist delete command asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, guid, datalist, delete-row

i need help about GUID auto generate datatype treated as primary key. I don't know how to use this in delete command in datalist. Can anyone help me with an example coding of delete command in datalist with GUID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer: [c# Datalist delete specific row.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285425/c-sharp-datalist-delete-specific-row) you can see how he deletes using an int identifier.

Guid shouldn't be different.

If you have a specific error with the guid type, then post a more detailed question and state what have you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: just tell me one thing when we put any entry in database in new row then GUID automatically generate unique id or we have to write some code for that ??

Comment: You didn't indicate which database you're using, but for code generated guid use System.Guid.NewGuid() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx)